# At what stage in compiling does syntactic sugar generally become "desugared"

Tags: compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, syntactic-sugar

I'm curious as to how and when a compiler "desugars" syntactic sugar into it's final form. An example of syntatic sugar is a increment statement `i++` turning into a assign statement `i=i+1`, or languages that support operator overloading.

I know that many different compilers will implement the "desugaring" process in different ways and at different stages, so I'd be happy with rough examples from any language.

By stages I'm referring to the various different phases of the compiling process such as parsing, semantic analysis, intermediate, code generation etc.

I'm particularly interested about the effects (if any) on the AST and any potential transformations that will occur to it.

Comment: It has definitely happened before code generation :-). Beyond that, I don't think there's a better answer than "it depends". At least, I'm not going to try one. (Postfix `++` is more complicated than a simple substitution with `(x = x + 1)`, because the return value of that replacement expression is the new value of `x`, but the semantics of postfix increment require that the return value be the old value.)

Comment: @rici While I understand why you made your reply a comment, in this case because the question is more subjective than objective, I think you should post that as an answer so that others can see the question has an answer. I would upvote that as an answer and accept it if I were the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I will take a different approach in answering this question. Rather than focusing on phases I will focus on the intermediate languages.

As mentioned by @rici in the comments to this question this does indeed depend. In many modern-day compilers, different intermediate representations are used:

1. HIR (High-Level Intermediate Representation) (Frontend & "Midend")
2. MIR (Mid-level intermediate representation) (Midend & Backend)
3. LIR (Low-Level Intermediate Representation) (Backend)

These different intermediate representations may, in turn, be subdivided, for instance, HIR-1 (With Sugar) HIR-2 (With sugar expanded)

As we transition between the different intermediate representations our intermediate language becomes less language-specific and more target-specific. The Mid-level intermediate representation typically resembles a low-level machine-independent language whereas the LIR typically is very close to the target machine. Typically different variants of the HIR keep things such as loops and array access explicit and it is used for instance to check for opportunities to automatically parallelize code or do other optimizations relating to looping constructs. Sometimes more language-specific optimizations (or checks) might also be found there.

In the case of syntactic sugar, it will either be kept after parsing and thus be a part of some HIR representation or the designer might have opted to desugarize it directly. The advantage of keeping it after parsing is that it can be used for instance in tools that provide tips to users or that there is some syntactic sugar that can be used in some HIR optimization. The disadvantage of keeping it is that the sugar needs to be encoded and may introduce more code and more checks in the compiler.